# C Standard Version Check

Tags: c, c89

- Platform: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Compiler: GCC 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

I am writing a header that needs to be backwards complaint with C90. I have some optional functions that are included if the complier supports C99 or C11. So I use the standard feature test macros. I just want to know if the way I do this is correct.

```
#if __STDC__
   //code
#endif

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199000L
    //code
#endif

#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201100L
   //code
#endif
```

I am assuming that if the compiler is strictly C90 or C89 then the compiler will error out and say `__STDC_VERSION__` is undefined am I correct? If so should I use defined()? For example `#if defined(__STDC__)` rather than just `#if __STDC__`.

Comment: IIRC, undefined macros are replaced with `0`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: In that context, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined identifiers in preprocessor-conditionals are replaced by 0 if they are not argument to `define`, thus no error:

> #### 6.10.1 Conditional inclusion
>
> 3 Preprocessing directives of the forms
>
> ```
> #if constant-expression new-line groupopt
> #elif constant-expression new-line groupopt
> ```
>
> check whether the controlling constant expression evaluates to nonzero.
>   4 Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing tokens that will become
>   the controlling constant expression are replaced (except for those macro names modified
>   by the defined unary operator), just as in normal text. If the token defined is
>   generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the defined unary operator
>   does not match one of the two specified forms prior to macro replacement, the behavior is
>   undefined. **After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary
>   operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically
>   identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0**, and then each preprocessing
>   token is converted into a token. [...]

You can use the `#error` directive to force a compilation-error.